# Calculus tangent lines

Tags: calculus

I'm given some equations.

The first one, $x^3+2x^2-8x+1$ wants me to find the tangent line at $x=2$.

The second, (x^1.5) - (x^1/2) wants me to find the tangent line at $x=4$.

How would I go about solving this algebraically? I have to be able to prove the answers are $y=12x-23$ and $y=2.75x-5$ respectively, but I don't know how to start.

Comment: What important idea of calculus tells you the slope of the tangent line of a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tangent line can be written as
$$
y = m x + b
$$
Here, $m$ would be equal to the slope, and at the tangent line, the slope is equal to the derivative of a function in consideration. Thus for your first function, the derivative at $x=2$ will have
$$
\frac{dx^3+2x^2-8x+1}{dx}|_{x=2} = 3x^2+4x-8|_{x=2}= 12.
$$
Thus, the tangent line will take the form of
$$
y  = 12x+b.
$$
Now, to find $b$ you would notice that the tangent line intersects the function at $x=2$. The function value at $x=2$ is equal to $2^3+2(2^2)-8(2)+1 = 1$, thus we need to have $(x,y)= (2,1)$ to be a solution of the tangent line, and this would be satisfied when
$$
1 = 12(2)+b
$$
i.e. $b=-23$.
Thus the functional for for the tangent line would be 
$$
y  = 12x-23.
$$
Similar arguments would work for the other questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function $f(x)$, then at a given point $x_0$, the tangent line has slope $f'(x_0)$ and goes through the point $(x_0, f(x_0))$.  The general equation of a line through a point $(x_0, y_0)$ and slope $m$ is

$$
y-y_0 = m(x-x_0)
$$

So in the first problem, $x_0 = 2$ and $f(x) = x^3+2x^2-8x+1$.  Figure out what $f(x_0)$ and $f'(x_0)$ are, and proceed.